# Examples of mid-open and mid-closed vowels in Russian

Tags: фонетика, vowel

I am looking for Russian word pairs illustrating the distinction between mid-open and mid-closed vowels. Although the distinction is not significant in Russian, both types are probably realized, which could be useful for studying foreign languages.

One such example that I have seen in a French language textbook for the front mid-closed/open pair is "п**е**нь/**э**то". I am interested in more examples, but mostly in an example of rear mid-open/closed vowel.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distinction"? Open-mid and close-mid vowels have different frequency spectra, and they are, by definition, distinct, you don't need Russian words to illustrate that. Are you looking for words with the same phoneme realized as two different allophones, open-mid and close-mid? Or two words with different phonemes, to illustrate that Russian has both open-mid and close-mid vowels in its phonetic inventory and the openness can serve as a phonemic distinction in Russian?

Comment: @Quassnoi by lack of distinction I mean that they are allophones (in Russian). I am looking for examples of different phonemes realized in Russian in order to improve my pronunciation in other languages (I am a native Russian speaker, and perhaps bot the moat phonetically talented.)

Answer (score 2):

In Standard Russian, there is no distinction between /o/ and /ɔ/. In some dialects, though, there are minimal pairs like /kot/ 'cat' and /kɔd/ 'code.'

[e] and [ɛ] are not really contrasted in some positions (e.g., word-initially); there is almost free variation. Stressed [e] is used after palatalized/palatal consonants ([ˈtʲeɾmʲɪn] 'term'), and stressed [ɛ] after velarized/velar consonants ([ˈtɛɾməs] 'thermos').

Answer (score 1):

The pair это/эти could be an example of the /e/ phoneme expressed as two allophones of different 'openness'.

Comment: Nice! Do you know of an example for [o] vs. [ɔ] ?